# LoadBalance Failed after add CorsConfiguration

Tags: spring-boot, cross-domain, spring-cloud-gateway, spring-cloud-loadbalancer, nacos

environment:

1. Spring cloud version: 2020.0.2, Spring-cloud-starter-alibaba-nacos version: 2021.1
2. I have already exclude the netflix-ribbon and import spring-cloude-starter-loadbalancer in pom.xml, and use "lb://url" formate in gateway config

problem:
I need Spring Cloud Gateway Cors cross-domain operation. Therefore, based on the solution online (https://www.programmerall.com/article/5764552098/), I set the addtional Mono filter. For cross-domain, this solution works fine. However, the default loadbalancer (rotation) in nacos does not work with this cross-domain strategy. Is any possible solution to make cross-domain work with loadbalancer in nacos?

Thank you

Comment: Anyway, found the solution. Just use the filter strategy provided by NACOS, "spring.cloud.gateway.default-filters:DedupeResponseHeader=Access-Control-Allow-Origin Access-Control-Allow-Credentials,RETAIN_UNIQUE"